# Can we add custom tabs in slack apps ? Currently it has only home, messages and about

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit, slack-dialog

Can we add custom tabs in slack apps ? Currently it has only home, messages and about.

I have checked slack documentation but didn't found anything related to this topic.

I want to add Completed and Pending Tabs along with home and about in slack application